# Restrict Enum parameter to certain Enum types (at compile-time)

Tags: c#, enums

I created a `static void Method (Enum myEnum)`, but I'd like to feed it only certain Enum types, or face my mistake at compile-time. As I'm experimenting a lot with my code (using gameplay mechanics as shader variants), I need to change the accepted types on a whim, with the least possible maintenance of the `Method` class.

Basically, I'm struggling to do with enums what I could have very easily done working with classes (create a shared base class to use as parameter type). The first that came to mind were attributes:

- Can a custom attribute affect compilation in any way? I'd be surprised if it could.
- Can I mimic class inheritance in **any** way for Enum types, albeit just to create some kind of category to restrict method parameters?

This is my impossible dream code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
public class ShaderVariant : System.Attribute { }

void Method (T myEnum) where T : [ShaderVariant]Enum { }
```

My current options are:

- Create the aforementioned attribute to tag the selected Enum declarations, and react to it during runtime (throw an ArgumentException if myEnum.GetType() doesn't have the attribute). This approach silently allows me to mess up while coding, but only having to add/remove an attribute to any Enum I want is my dream-workflow.
- Declare a ludicrous amount of wrapper overloads for each type and forever maintain the `Method` class, doomed to commit the same file over and over again for every slight change made to the project. But works at compile-time.

**This question is about how C# works**. I know it's easier to create the wrapper overloads, but it feels wrong subjugating the handler method to support what essentially is a parameter property.

Comment: Maybe separate inherited classes.  The you can check by using typeof() instead of using enumerations.  Each inherited class will have a different type.

Comment: I don't think the type system (as it is now) supports what you want. Why don't you make them classes (with a private constructor and limited instances), and then mark them with an interface? This ensures compile time type safety and should probably let you avoid having to maintain the method (by using virtual methods of the interface). Enums are only good for scenarios that are simpler than yours and will not need to get more complicated in the future.

Comment: I've already seen solutions that replace the Enums with classes. My enums are state variables that are used all thorught the code as any normal Enum would. Suggesting to use classes basically means implementing my own Enum system to use for all the enums in the project.

Comment: @EmilioMartinez I don't think it would be as hard as you imagine. (Especially if you restrict instance creation and use them as singletons, you get things like equality comparisons for free.) Anyway, I wouldn't try to persuade you into changing your code. I'm just pointing out that enums are too simple (in terms of capabilities) and you are trying to do something that's not very simple.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yes, thanks a lot, I had been searching a lot and my current best answer is your "The type system (as it is now) does not support what you want".

Answer (score 0):

Enums are simply short names for constant numbers. 
If members of an Enum are different, as some has to be acceptable in Compile time to a method and some not.. then maybe you need two Enums. One will have members acceptable to a method an one having all possible options.

Enums are very simple structures without inheritance. If you see feel like you need inheritance, then you probably should not use Enum and use classes.

Comment: I want to distinguish between Enum types, not Enum members

Comment: .Net distinguishes between enum types, but you don't get inheritance or other OO features for it.